# In powershell $x.FullName not returning full path

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script below which takes a config file and deletes files older than x days matching a regular expression.

Config File:

```
path,pattern,days,testrun
C:\logs\,^data_access_listener.log,7,false
```

However here is what is output:

```
Would have deleted 000a19f6-a982-4f77-88be-ca9cc51a2bcbuu_data_access_listener.log
Would have deleted 00189746-2d46-4cdd-a5bb-6fed4bee25a7uu_data_access_listener.log
```

I'm expecting the output to include the full file path since I'm using the .FullName attribute so I'd expect output as such:

```
Would have deleted C:\logs\000a19f6-a982-4f77-88be-ca9cc51a2bcbuu_data_access_listener.log
Would have deleted C:\logs\00189746-2d46-4cdd-a5bb-6fed4bee25a7uu_data_access_listener.log
```

If I am using $x.FullName why am I not getting the full name with path (C:\logs)?

Thanks
Brad

```
$LogFile = "C:\deletefiles.log"
$Config = import-csv -path C:\config.txt

function DeleteFiles ([string]$path, [string]$pattern, [int]$days, [string]$testrun){
    $a =  Get-ChildItem $path -recurse | where-object {$_.Name -notmatch $pattern}    
    foreach($x in $a) {
    $y = ((Get-Date) - $x.LastWriteTime).Days
        if ($y -gt $days -and $x.PsISContainer -ne $True) {

            if ($testrun -eq "false") {
                write-output “Deleted" $x.FullName >>$LogFile 
            } else {
                write-output “Would have deleted $x” >>$LogFile 
            }


        }
    }
}

foreach ($line in $Config) {
    $path = $line.path
    $pattern = $line.pattern
    $days = $line.days
    $testrun = $line.testrun

    DeleteFiles $path $pattern $days
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like a typo. You are not using FullName in the condition that leads to "Would have Deleted". Change:

```
write-output “Would have deleted $x” >>$LogFile
```

to:

```
write-output “Would have deleted " $x.FullName >>$LogFile
```

To answer your comment, if you want to call a property on a variable that is expanded in the string, you have to surround it in `$()`, so that the parser knows to invoke the whole expression. Like this:

```
write-output “Would have deleted $($x.FullName)" >>$LogFile
```

Comment: I was modifying the if statement ($testrun -eq "false") when the else statement is what was executing. I noticed if I do “Would have deleted $x.FullName" I do not get the full path. If I do “Would have deleted " $x.FullName, I do get the complete path. Any idea why it works outside of quotes but not inside? Additionally outside of quotes I get an extra line break so for instance would have deleted <line break> C:\logs\file.log. I'd rather not have the linebreak if possible.